# How to create npm package with definition files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

How to create an NPM package with definition files where declared only interfaces in `*.ts` files.

Let's suppose we have two interfaces and one class defination:

```
export interface A {
 id: number;
}

export interface B {
 name: string;
}

export class C {
}
```

I need to pack these `*.ts` files in package npm, how to do that? Should I export them in `index.ts`?

My `package.json` is:

```
{
  "name": "npm",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

My `tsconfig.json` is:

```
"compilerOptions": {
   "target": "es5", /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
   "module": "commonjs",
   "strict": true, 
   "esModuleInterop": true, 
   "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true   
}
```

Inside `index.ts` there is:

```
import { A } from "./a";
import { B } from "./b";
import { C } from "./c";
```

Where `'./a', './b', './c'` is files with declarations of interfaces and classes.

When I build it to `index.js` file using command: `tsc index.ts` then I can not get access to interfaces using module `index.js` in others projects (npm install )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To bundle the types with your package, there are two specific things for you to do:

1. **Set `"declaration"` to `true` in `tsconfig.json`.** This tells TypeScript to generate `*.d.ts` files.
2. **Set `"types"` in `package.json`.** This tells TypeScript where to find generated `*.d.ts` files.

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "declaration": true  <----------------------
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "types": "index.d.ts", <----------------------
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  }
}
```

Here is a [working example for you on GitHub](https://github.com/shaunluttin/typescript-publishing-type-definitions). All of the above and more details are [hidden in the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html#including-declarations-in-your-npm-package).

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods to publish definiton files:

1. bundling with your npm package,
2. or publishing to the [@types organization](https://www.npmjs.com/~types) on npm.

Here is [the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html) to help you with that

Comment: So, do you mean there are two packages one is implementation package, another one is declaration @types? In my case what is it?

Comment: As you are using TypeScript, you can use the first option