# NPM Custom Package : Compile And Export TypeScript Interfaces

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, npm

## Question: Am I missing some TS configuration, or some TS build step?

I have created a new npm package:

> **Custom-NPM-Package /**
>
> - src
>
> -- index.js
>
> -- index.d.ts
>
> -- IType.ts

with this tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "CommonJS", 
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "./dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react",

    "outDir": "./dist", 
    "rootDir": "./src", 
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true, 
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*.ts", 
    "./src/**/*.tsx", 
    "./src/**/*.jsx" 
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules", 
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

The goal is to import the Types from other projects (React),

1. Install the package:

> npm install Custom-NPM-Package

2. Import TS Type:

> import { IType } from 'Custom-NPM-Package'

but I'm having an error:

> ./node_modules/Custom-NPM-Package/dist/index.js
> export 'IType' (reexported as 'IType') was not found in './IType' (possible exports: IType, __esModule)

Comment: In the custom package, is the `types` or `typings` field set in its package.json?

Comment: @adsy yes i have created a folder types containing `index.js` and `index.d.ts` and in package.json i point to it like this :  `"types": "dist/index.d.ts"`, but my problem is that i have a types subfolder in each folder ex : `src/stack/types/ITypeA.ts`, `src/stack/types/ITypeB.ts` ... so the error is only for the `ts` files and not the `tsx`

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution here:

[How to create npm package with definition files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60839051/how-to-create-npm-package-with-definition-files)

1. Set "declaration" to true in *tsconfig.json*. This tells TypeScript to generate **.d.ts*
2. Set "types" in *package.json*. This tells TypeScript where to find generated *.d.ts files.

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "declaration": true  <--
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "types": "index.d.ts", <--
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  }
}
```

Note if you have a multiple ts interfaces exemple:

- src 
  -- componentA/Types/ 
  -- componentA/Types/ IntefacesA.TS 

  -- componentB/Types/ 
  -- componentB/Types/ IntefacesB.TS

you can create another (types for exemple) folder in **src**:

- src
  -- src/types

and create an *index.ts* file inside; import your types and exports them :

**index.ts**:

```
import { IIntefacesA } from './componentA/Types/IntefacesA';
import { IIntefacesB } from './componentA/Types/IntefacesB';

export type { IIntefacesA, IIntefacesB };
```

and point to this folder from your **src**/*index.d.ts* and *index.js*:

**index.d.ts** / **index.js**

```
export * from './ReactComponent1';
export * from './ReactComponentX';
export * from './types';
```